# Why does Qt use a signed integer type for its container classes?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

The question is clear.

I wonder why they even thought this would be handy, as clearly negative indices are unusable in the containers that would be used with them (see for example [`QList`'s docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlist.html#indexOf)).

I thought they wanted to allow that for some crazy form of indexing, but it seems unsupported?

It also generates a ton of (correct) compiler warnings about casting to and comparing of signed/unsigned types (on MSVC).

It just seems incompatible with the STL by design for some reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, realistically, you usually want to perform arithmetic on indices, which means that you might want to create temporaries that are negative.
This is clearly painful when the underlying indexing type is unsigned.

The only appropriate time to use unsigned numbers is with modulus arithmetic.
Using "unsgined" as some kind of contract specifier "a number in the range [0..." is just clumsy, and too coarse to be useful.

Consider: What type should I use to represent the idea that the number should be a positive integer between 1 and 10? Why is 0...2^x a more special range?

Comment: "only" is a rather strong specifier, there.

Comment: The one special case, is an array of [signed/unsigned] char's. In which case modulus arithmetic yields the same result on two's complement representation platforms

Comment: I agree with the more general point, though, that unsigned types are overrated in their commonly-used role as documentation.

Comment: @Chris: this sounds like you think signed size types are a defect in the C++ Standard? I never heard/read anyone complaining about C++ container index arithmatic with regard to eg `std::vector` indeces?

Comment: @Chris: but the wraparound is potentially nasty because it means that your array indices go 0, 1, 2, 32766, 32767, -32768, -32767, ..., and you can no longer say that `x` is before `y` in the array iff the index of `x` is smaller than the index of `y`. That said, mixing unsigned and signed quantities tends to lead to bugs that are approximately as bad as the bugs that would result if people had to remember to convert indices to an unsigned type before comparing them, and far more likely to actually occur in practice.

Comment: So we have been saddled with a stupid and dangerous definition of size_t, to ensure that an extreme edge case of using a char array to index memory doesn't suffer undesirable undefined behavior on the tiny number of remaining non two's complement cpu models.

Comment: @Sapph - there are only two defensible uses for using unsigned. For modulus arithmetic (which covers the char array indexing all of a 32bit PCs memory with overflow acting in a defined way), and as a cheap substitute for contract semantics. The lack of a rich contract documentation standard renders that use dubious at best.

Comment: It makes no difference whether the CPU is 2's complement or not, *if* your array indexes are signed, and furthermore *if* an implementation wants to provide arrays which are bigger than half the range of that signed type, *then* array index comparisons suddenly make no sense. It's much less problematic on average than unsigned sizes, but when it's problematic it's unacceptable to the committee. And in general yes, in C++ we are saddled with certain design decisions which could have been avoided if it (and C) were designed to be less portable.

Comment: @rubenvb: Oh, many people do (complain). Mostly programmers using languages that do not support unsigned arithmetic, and they consider as such 'dangerous'; however, when used correctly, it's not.

Comment: @Steve using any non char type means that, at the point a signed quantity would wrap around, the unsigned quantity would index past the available memory anyway (and wrap around). The ultimate result is the same whether the index is signed or unsigned: some "random" memory location gets indexed.

Comment: @Chris: True, but "unacceptably bad" (in the opinion of the committee) is unacceptable whether it applies to all arrays, or just to arrays of chars. Perhaps a better solution would have been to shaft the 16-bit micro programmers, by making `size_t` signed and saying that you just have to either use an inefficient two-word type for it, or else accept that offsets into 32k char arrays (of which "my RAM" might be a key example) can't be compared with `<` in a way that makes sense. But I can easily say that, as someone who doesn't care what C is like on 16-bit micros because I don't program them.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm saying that the committee thinks that such-and-such situation is so bad that it won't be tolerated in the standard, even if it means some other situation that you hate more than they do. If sensible indices are a red line for the committee then it doesn't matter whether they become non-sensible in 1% of implementations or 0.00001%, they aren't going to write the standard that way. Us mere mortals just have to learn to use unsigned quantities safely. Even if it's now 0%, it's too late to change the standard: use Java instead (more realistically: use Qt instead).

Comment: "size_t considered harmful" :P

Comment: "some "random" memory location gets indexed" - oh, hang on, no. If I have a 64k address space, I allocate 48k, and `malloc` gives me back a pointer value in the first 16k of the space, then (and pretty much only then), unsigned indices are clearly superior to signed. With signed indices, the last 16k of my array has negative indices: with unsigned nothing wraps or needs to wrap. Of course when I do the pointer arithmetic with those negative indices, in practice I'll get the right answer, but when I do `if (i < j)` for arbitrary pairs of signed indices I get astonishing results.

Comment: The rationale says: "The Standard, like K&R, defines the result of the sizeof operator to be a constant of an unsigned integral type. Common implementations, and common usage, have often assumed that the resulting type is int. Old code that depends on this behavior has never been portable to implementations that define the result to be a type other than int. The C89 Committee did not feel it was proper to change the language to protect incorrect code."

Comment: Accepted, because the comment discussion is very interesting :)

Answer (score 12):

Although I am deeply sympathetic to Chris's line of reasoning, I will disagree here (at least in part, I am playing devil's advocate).  There is nothing wrong with using unsigned types for sizes, and it can even be beneficial in some circumstances.

Chris's justification for signed size types is that they are naturally used as array indices, and you may want to do arithmetic on array indices, and that arithmetic may create temporary values that are negative.

That's fine, and unsigned arithmetic introduces no problem in doing so, as long as you make sure to interpret your values correctly when you do comparisons.  Because the overflow behavior of unsigned integers is fully specified, temporary overflows into the negative range (or into huge positive numbers) do not introduce any error as long as they are corrected before a comparison is performed.

Sometimes, the overflow behavior is even desirable, as the overflow behavior of unsigned arithmetic makes certain range checks expressible as a single comparison that would require two comparisons otherwise.  If I want to check if `x` is in the range `[a,b]` and all the values are unsigned, I can simply do:

```
if (x - a < b - a) {
}
```

That doesn't work with signed variables; such range checks are pretty common with sizes and array offsets.

I mentioned before that a benefit is that overflow arithmetic has defined results.  If your index arithmetic overflows a signed type, the behavior is implementation defined; there is no way to make your program portable.  Use an unsigned type and this problem goes away.  Admittedly this only applies to *huge* offsets, but it is a concern for some uses.

Basically, the objections to unsigned types are frequently overstated.  The real problem is that most programmers don't really think about the exact semantics of the code they write, and for **small** integer values, signed types behave more nearly in line with their intuition.  However, data sizes grow pretty fast.  When we deal with buffers or databases, we're frequently way outside of the range of "small", and signed overflow is far more problematic to handle correctly than is unsigned overflow.  The solution is not "don't use unsigned types", it is "think carefully about the code you are writing, and make sure you understand it".

Comment: I do really like the lazy underflow check style possible with unsigned indexes.

Comment: @stephen. do you mean (x - a < b - a)? This is similar to the trick of checking a signed value in the interval [0,b] (unsigned(x) < b) suffices.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Yes.