# Why size of QByteArray is `int` rather than `unsigned int`

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have such expressions in my code:

```
QByteArray idx0 = ...

unsigned short ushortIdx0;

if ( idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0) ) {
    // Do something
}
```

But I'm getting the warning:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
>
> ```
> if ( idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0) ) {
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Why `size()` of `QByteArray` is returned as `int` rather than `unsigned int`? How can I get rid of this warning safely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Qt use a signed integer type for its container classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030132/why-does-qt-use-a-signed-integer-type-for-its-container-classes)

Comment: A nice documented answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26621565/6165833

Comment: Knowing why is a duplicate issue - such knowledge does in no way impact how you can get rid of this warning. How to fix the comparison is very much a valid question, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some folk feel that the introduction of `unsigned` types into C all those years ago was a bad idea. Such types found themselves introduced into C++, where they are deeply embedded in the C++ Standard Library and operator return types.

Yes, `sizeof` must, by the standard, return an `unsigned` type.

The Qt developers adopt the modern thinking that the `unsigned` types were a bad idea, and favour instead making the return type of `size` a `signed` type. Personally I find it idiosyncratic.

To solve, you could (i) live with the warning, (ii) switch it off for the duration of the function, or (iii) write something like

```
(std::size_t)idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0)
```

at the expense of clarity.

Comment: _"The Qt developers adopt the modern thinking"_ where did you get this? I raised an issue some years ago to switch Qt to `size_t` which was refused but based only on the fact that it would involve too much changes, there were not ideological objections.

Comment: @ixSci: Was there a discussion about it? Can you give us a link?

Comment: @geza, I will try to find it in a few hours. It was before the Qt5 release and since then there were many movements of the Qt-related resources back-and-forth, so no promises.

Comment: *"`(std::size_t)idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0)`"*. That assumes `idx0.size()` is non negative, else that would probably fails OP's intention :-) On the other hand, casting `sizeof(ushortIdx0)` to `signed` would be UB for very huge `ushortIdx0` :-). `idx0.size() >= 0 && (std::size_t)idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0)`, joice of mixing unsigned with signed :-/

Comment: @Jarod42: If the size of something was ever negative then I think we could all have a very robust conversation with the development team.

Comment: They could return *"conventional"* `-1` for *"invalid"* objects.

Comment: @Jarod42: That would cause an even more robust conversation and even if that were the case, you'd have to check that possibility before proceeding with the loop.

Comment: BTW, that explain the warning which can cause *unexpected* results depending of possible values and implicit conversion/promotion.

Comment: @geza, found the [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/189/qt-containers-inadequate-to-x64/18) but it turned out there was no answer from any of the devs. Still there was no indication of the devs' (it was Nokia at the time, I believe) dedication to the signed integers because of some _thinking_. The absence of an answer is telling also because as far as I remember at least a couple of the devs were pretty active at the forum at the time.

Comment: @ixSci: Thanks! They definitely didn't think that through well, as they should have used a `size_t` sized integer for size.

Answer (score 4):

> Why size() of QByteArray is returned as int rather than unsigned int?

I literally have no idea why Qt chose a signed return for `size()`. However, there are good reasons to use a signed instead of an unsigned.

One infamous example where a `unsigned size()` fails miserably is this quite innocent looking loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_container.size() - 1; ++i) {
     do_somehting(some_container[i] , some_container[i+1] );
}
```

Its not too uncommon to make the loop body operate on two elements and in that case its seems to be a valid choice to iterate only till `some_container.size() - 1`.

However, if the container is empty `some_container.size() - 1` will silently (unsigned overflow is well defined) turn into the biggest value for the unsigned type. Hence, instead of avoiding the out-of-bounds access it leads to the maximum out of bounds you can get.

Note that there are easy fixes for this problem, but if `size()` does return a signed value, then there is no issue that needs to be fixed in the first place.

Comment: Yup, I answered a question on this some time ago. The obvious solution is `i + 1 < some_container.size()`. Not really an answer to the question but upvoted anyway as it's important!

Comment: @Batsheba yeah it is of course easy to fix, but it isnt nice that there is an issue to be fixed in the first place. Also not all occurences of this kind of bugs are that easy to spot

Comment: It's what the slide operator was invented for!

Comment: @Bathsheba the what operator?

Answer (score 3):

Because in Qt containers (like: QByteArray, QVector, ...) there are functions which can return a negative number, like: indexOf, lastIndexOf, contains, ... and some can accept negative numbers, like: mid, ...; So to be class-compatible or even framework-compatibe, developers use a signed type (int).

You can use standard c++ casting:

```
if ( static_cast<size_t>(idx0.size()) >= sizeof(ushortIdx0) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is a duplicate part of the question, but the solution to the type mismatch is a valid problem to solve. For the comparisons of the kind you're doing, it'd probably be useful to factor them out, as they have a certain reusable meaning:

```
template <typename T> bool fitsIn(const QByteArray &a) {
  return static_cast<int>(sizeof(T)) <= a.size();
}

template <typename T> bool fitsIn(T, const QByteArray &a) {
  return fitsIn<T>(a);
}

if (fitsIn(ushortIdx0, idx0)) ...
```

Hopefully you'll have just a few kinds of such comparisons, and it'd make most sense to DRY (do not repeat yourself) and instead of a copypasta of casts, use functions dedicated to the task - functions that also express the intent of the original comparison. It then becomes easy to centralize handling of any corner cases you might wish to handle, i.e. when `sizeof(T) > INT_MAX`.

Another approach would be to define a new type to wrap `size_t` and adapt it to the types you need to use it with:

```
class size_of {
  size_t val;
  template <typename T> static typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, size_t>::type fromSigned(T sVal) {
    return (sVal > 0) ? static_cast<size_t>(sVal) : 0;
  }
public:
  template <typename T, typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<T>::value>::type> 
  size_of(const T&) : val(sizeof(T)) {}
  size_of(const QByteArray &a) : val(fromSigned(a.size())) {}
  ...
  bool operator>=(size_of o) const { return value >= o.value; }
};

if (size_of(idx0) >= size_of(ushortIdx0)) ...
```

This would conceptually extend `sizeof` and specialize it for comparison(s) and nothing else.