# Is there a signed `sizeof` alternative in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Sizes of Qt containers return (signed) `int`. And we know in Qt, a lot more is using `int` instead of the unsigned type `size_t` in order to do arithmetic operations without the need for casting. See [Why does Qt use a signed int type for its container classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030132/why-does-qt-use-a-signed-integer-type-for-its-container-classes) & [Why QVector.size() returns int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030132/why-does-qt-use-a-signed-integer-type-for-its-container-classes)

As the language keyword `sizeof` returns the `size_t` type, is there a Qt alternative for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your own, safe version:

```
template<std::size_t s>
constexpr int safeIntCast()
{
    static_assert(s <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), "Type too large for ssizeof()!");
    return static_cast<int>(s);
}

#define ssizeof(x) safeIntCast<sizeof(x)>()

/// Usage

static_assert(ssizeof(int) == 4);
static_assert(ssizeof(1.0) == 8);

static_assert(ssizeof(std::declval<int>()) == 4);
static_assert(ssizeof(int[1000000000000]) > 4); // Conversion problem is caught!
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Cwfy8)

It has the same semantics as `sizeof` but yields an `int` while ensuring that the conversion does not overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that this is impossible. `std::size_t` can be `std::uintmax_t`, meaning that even `std::intmax_t`, the largest standards compliant type, cannot hold all values of `std::size_t`.

In most cases, you won't have to worry about it. An `int` (or a `long long`) will hold the size of your objects in most cases, so you can just cast to it: `static_cast<long long>(sizeof(T))`. If you are doing pointer arithmetic, consider using `std::ptrdiff_t`, or not using `sizeof` and doing `end() - begin()`.